# Why is Microsoft Report Viewer Runtime 2015 libraries not showing in the Add Reference window and does not display on the form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, rdlc

I just finished upgrading my vb.net project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2013 and then I have to add new reports(.rdlc) files.

The problem is that I think that the new rdlc xml format of VS2013 is not compatible with the old Microsoft Report Viewer Version 9.0(Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms) so I needed to download and install the new Report Viewer Runtime 2015(Version 12.0)

But after installing the Microsoft ReportViewer Runtime 2015, I cannot find it in the Add Reference Dialog. Only Version 9 and Version 10 of the Report Viewer is still showing.

Furthermore, when I drag and drop a report viewer control in the form, it does not display but stays in the bottom(like a background worker component).

Comment: I ended up browsing and referencing the actual file from c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll and c:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll to load the assembly in VS2013